# how to build a NSPredicate filtering all days in a month using NSDate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nspredicate

Is there a way to get all days in a month generically ?

Something like this:

`[NSPredicate predicatewithFormat@"(date.firstDayOfMonth >= @)AND(date.lastDayOfMonth <= @)"];`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  You need to figure out what the first *instant* of the month is, as well as the first instant of the next month.  Here's how I would do it:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [calendar components:NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[nowComponents setDay:1];

NSDate *beginningOfCurrentMonth = [calendar dateFromComponents:nowComponents];

NSDateComponents *oneMonth = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[oneMonth setMonth:1];

NSDate *beginningOfNextMonth = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneMonth toDate:beginningOfCurrentMonth options:0];
```

Once you've got those two `NSDate`s, then you can do:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND date < %@", beginningOfCurrentMonth, beginningOfNextMonth];
```