# Filter fetchRequest for year/month using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdate, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have an app that has several time entries with a date saved as NSDate.

I would like to use a fetch request to filter for a certain year and month that I get from somewhere else. How can I use NSPredicate to filter for a year and month?

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %D && %K == %D", ???, selectedMonth, ???, selectedYear)
```

**Update**

Using the help Raki pointed out I came up with the following code:

```
var dateComp = DateComponents()
dateComp.year = Int(selectedYear)
dateComp.month = Int(selectedMonth)
dateComp.day = 1
    
let calendar = Calendar.current
let firstDayOfTheMonth = calendar.date(from: dateComp)
    
var oneMonth = DateComponents()
oneMonth.month = 1
let beginningOfNextMonth = calendar.date(byAdding: oneMonth, to: firstDayOfTheMonth!)
```

And the predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date < %@", firstDayOfTheMonth as! CVarArg, beginningOfNextMonth as! CVarArg)
```

I get a SIGABRT with the following message:

> Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.Date' (0x1073a0ae0) to 'Swift.CVarArg' (0x1196851c8).

Xcode suggested I add "as! CVarArg"

**Update 2**

The following predicate worked now:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %@ && %K < %@", "date", firstDayOfTheMonth! as NSDate, "date", beginningOfNextMonth! as NSDate)
```

Comment: what is the format of date that you are saving?

Comment: I'm using NSDate. In CoreData type 'Date'.

Comment: it may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262567/how-to-build-a-nspredicate-filtering-all-days-in-a-month-using-nsdate

Comment: Thanks raki. But now I get another problem with the fetchRequest at runtime. See above...

Comment: for your new problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587046/cant-pass-date-to-nspredicateformat-without-as-cvararg

Comment: Thanks it works now. Great help ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot predicate like this, but you can create two `Dates` from your month and year which start day of month and end day of month.

Now you need to simply predicate like this way.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %@ && %K <= %@", "DateAttribute", startDateOfMonth as NSDate, "DateAttribute", endDateOfMonth as NSDate)
```

**Edit:** If you don't know how to create date for `startDateOfMonth` and `endDateOfMonth`, then you can create it using `DateComponents`.

```
let selectedMonth = 11
let selectedYear = 2015
var components = DateComponents()
components.month = selectedMonth
components.year = selectedYear
let startDateOfMonth = Calendar.current.date(from: components)

//Now create endDateOfMonth using startDateOfMonth
components.year = 0
components.month = 1
components.day = -1
let endDateOfMonth = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: startDate!)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just created it myself while you were typing... :P But I like components.day = -1. Didn't know that.

Comment: @user7259583 Is it working now, are you getting desired result?

Comment: @user7259583 Check the edited answer and with predicate type cast `Date` to `NSDate`. like `startDateOfMonth as NSDate`

Comment: Yes it works now. Used Date instead of NSDate. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user7259583 If you want to know how it is works then read this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60353

Comment: @user7259583 Welcome mate :)